# Use like operator and order by sub query

Tags: php, mysql

### Introduction

I have a project where we help the IT community to organize better IT meetups (just like meetup.com but only for IT community) called https://codotto.com/

We are developing a new feature where we would like to show the number of usages of certain tags. The algorithm should work just like Stackoverflow's one. You write `javascript` and you get a list with the tags that match your query sorted by the most used ones.

I'm currently using Laravel but I will post the raw query so that it's easier for mysql wizards to help me out if possible :)

### Problem

I have the following tables

*tags table*

```
id  name
1   javascript
2   javascript-tools
3   javascript-security
```

*group_has_tags table*

```
group_id  tag_id
1         2
2         2
2         3
```

We have the tags `javascript-tools` being used two times, `javascript-security` is used one while `javascript` is not used at all.

Now, if a user search for `javascript`, he should get first `javascript` (because it is a direct match) followed by the rest of the tags sorted by their usage.

In Laravel this is the code that I have (simplified ofc)

```php
$tags = Tag::withCount('groups')
  ->orderBy('groups_count', 'DESC')
  ->where('name', 'LIKE', 'javascript%')
  ->get(2);
```

The problem is that since I only return back `2` results, `javascript` is not being included in the results, even tho it's what the user literally wrote

[image]

For the mysql magicians, here is the raw query

```sql
select
  `tags`.*,
  (
    select
      count(*)
    from
      `meetups`
        inner join `meetup_has_tags` on `meetups`.`id` = `meetup_has_tags`.`meetup_id`
    where
        `tags`.`id` = `meetup_has_tags`.`tag_id`
  ) as `meetups_count`
from
  `tags`
where
    `title` LIKE 'javascript%'
order by
  `meetups_count` desc
limit
  2 offset 0
```

### Question

The main objective here is to return the most relevant result to the user. He writes `javascript` and `javascript` shows up first followed by less "relevant" results. The way I found was to sort by the number of times a tag was used.

Is there a solution where I can do "please, fetch the results that match this query first, then return the most relevant results"?

By "most relevant" results, I simply mean "what the user is looking for". If he writes "javascript" it should return "javascript" followed by "javascript-tools" (because "javascript-tools" was used twice but the user is literally searching for "javascript")

Comment: I'm starting to think that I'm over complicating things here. Why not simply return the results without order, only with `LIKE` and then on PHP side sort the values by most used one?! Will try this solution but in the meantime if anyone has a feedback would love to hear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT tags.*,COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group_has_tags WHERE tag_id = tags.id),0) AS usage
FROM tags
WHERE title LIKE 'javascript%') AS tmp
ORDER BY tmp.name = 'javascript' DESC,usage DESC
```

For each matching tag you get the number of times it has been used.
Then you first sort by whether the tag matches literally what the user has typed, then by the usage.
Of course you will have to parameterize this query but I hope you get the idea.